# Firestore Android Java -- How to get user document with Security Rules?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I believe my security rules and code is correct, but I am getting a permission error in Android studio when I try to retrieve from the user document...

This is the Get User Profile method in my Android java code:

```
public void getUserProfile(){
    db.collection("users")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String displayName = document.getString("DisplayName");
                            String userEmail = user.getEmail();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.w("DEBUG_FirestoreActivity", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

... and this is how my security rules are set up:

```
    match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;}
```

Here is the output of the error I'm receiving in android studio:

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

What's strange is that everything should work, and I have tested it with the Rules Playground.

Comment: Here is the output of the error I'm receiving in android studio:


    com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments. There's an edit link under your question, so you can add it there (as I just did).

Answer (score 0):

Your security rules allow each user to read their own document. But your code is trying to read the documents of all users, and is thus rejected.

Note that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) on their own. If you want to only read the current user's document, you need to do so from the code: the security rules won't do this for you.

For example:

```
db.collection("users")
  .doc(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .get()
```

Comment: `DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users")
        .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that comment?

Comment: The above code example worked for retrieving the user's document, with the security rules in place.